# How can I make Linux /var/log/syslog include CMD flags?

Tags: logging, ubuntu-12.04, syslog

Running Ubuntu 12.04. /var/log/syslog contains many entries like this:

Oct 26 15:10:01 ip-10-141-243-61 CRON[28264]: (bitnami) CMD (/bin/sh [obfuscated absolute path]/receiving_dock.sh)

a script I wrote.

It would be far more helpful if the syslog included the flags that follow the CMD, since then I could tell exactly what the system was doing (or trying to do). Is this possible?